# Me da error en el codigo

Tags: javascript

En el código que está dentro del if no me funciona pero cuando lo saco y pongo el código en la consola funciona, alguien que me pueda ayudar ahí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: añade tu código en forma de texto, dale en editar a tu pregunta y pégalo de modo contrario es dificil apoyarte

Comment: al momento de ejecutarse el `<SCRIPT>`, el elemento `BODY` aún no existe

Answer (score 2):

Bienvenido a la comunidad; espero poder ayudarte, pero como dice Alfredo, siempre es bueno que copies y pegues tu código como texto, para que nos sea fácil copiar y analizar.

El problema es la posición en donde ejecutas el script.
Primero se ejecuta el script y luego crea el DOM; Puedes utilizar el evento OnLoad, o agregar un listener para ello, o lo más fácil, puedes poner el script al final del body, de esta manera.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>document</title>

</head>
<body id="body">

    <script>
        let color = prompt("Elija azul con A) o amarillo con a)");
        if(color=='A'){
            document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
        if(color=='a'){
            document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes escribir un código más profesional y flexible con las siguientes ventajas:

- Un array que maneje los posibles colores. Esto permitirá incorporar con suma facilidad otros colores, agregándolos simplemente al array (puedes probar a incluir un nuevo par `"r" : "red"` en el array por ejemplo).
- Un `prompt` controlado que obligue a escribir valores válidos.
- La variable `cssColor` se definirá buscando en el array de colores el valor introducido. Si no existe, dará al fondo un valor por defecto (`gray` en el ejemplo de código).
- Dado que `body` permite tener un evento `onload`, podemos usar añadirle nuestra función a ese evento y nada más...

Espero te sea de utilidad.

```js
function changeBackground() {
  var arrColors = {
    "A": "blue",
    "a": "yellow"
  };

  var promptMessage = "Escribe [A] para Azul o [a] para amarillo";
  var promptWrited = prompt(promptMessage, "");
  while (!promptWrited) {
    promptWrited = prompt(promptMessage, "");
  }
  var cssColor = (typeof arrColors[promptWrited] == "undefined") ? "gray" : arrColors[promptWrited];

  document.body.style.background = cssColor;
}
```

```html
<body onload="changeBackground();">
```